# Subprocess Call to escape dynamically Powershell script by using variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell

I am trying to call the powershell Script with an argument from the my Python file .

When I am trying to call the Powershell script with the argument which is in the form of the variable , I am NOT able to escape the character . Here the variable contains the Name of the file ..

File in Directory : A_&_B

So Now I am looping through the directory and getting the file names using python . Now I need to send the File Name as argument to my powershell file

So `fileToPrint will be now A_&_B`

Python call

`subprocess.call(["Powershell.exe",PT.ps1,fileToPrint])`

Powershell Script

`$pptFileName=$args[0]
Write-Output ($pptFileName)`

When I print , I am getting `A_&` as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the file name with quotes.

```
subprocess.call(["Powershell.exe",PT.ps1,'"%s"' % fileToPrint])
```

Comment: '"%s"' % fileToPrint , why are we using %s here ?

Comment: @ashtav that's a printf-style type specifier for string. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting).